# Reference for the analytic valuative criterion of properness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

According to [this note](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/216APage/handouts/valcrit.pdf):

**Claim:** It can be shown that when $X$ is the “analytification” of
a separated $\mathbb{C}$-scheme of finite type then a sufficient condition for $X$ to be proper is that any holomorphic map $h\colon \Delta^∗ \to X$ extends to a holomorphic map $\Delta\to X$.

This seems to be an analytic version of the valuative criterion of properness. I have seen papers, math.stackexchange questions and even Wikipedia articles where similar results are applied or discussed. Nevertheless, I have not been able to find a reference where something like the claim stated above is actually proved.

I would appreciate it if someone could give me a reference.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know a reference, but here's a probable (I haven't double checked all the details) proof that's probably *way* overkill. We can assume throughout that $X$ is irreducible, as I leave it to you to check.

If $X$ is one-dimensional, this is easy. Indeed, we just directly verify that $X$ satisfies the existence part of the valuative criterion for properness (the uniqueness part follows from the assumption of separatedness). Indeed, let $\overline{X}$ be a projective closure of $X$ (note that $X$ is automatically quasi-projective--see [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A25)--so that this projective closure makes sense). Map a small disk $\Delta$ to $\overline{X}^\mathrm{an}$ such that $0\mapsto p\in \overline{X}-X$ for which $\Delta^\ast$ (the punctured disk) maps to $X$ (take a very small disk around any preimage point of $p$ in a normalization of $\overline{X}$) and consider the tautological map $\Delta^\ast\to X^\mathrm{an}$. This obviously cannot be extended to a map $\Delta\to X$ because by continuity the composition $\Delta\to \overline{X}^\mathrm{an}\to X$ must send $0$ to $p$, which is not in $X^\mathrm{an}$.

In general, let $\overline{X}$ be a compactification of $X$ which contains $X$ as a dense open (see [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ATT) and [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0F3T))--we may again assume WLOG that $\overline{X}$ is irreducible. Let $p$ be a point of $\overline{X}-X$ and $q$ a point of $X$, and let $C$ be a normal curve connecting $p$ and $q$ (e.g. see Corollary 1.9 of [this](https://klein.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/bertini_irred.pdf) and take normalization). Then, by the same trick as in the one-dimensional case build a map $\Delta\to C$ so that $0\mapsto p$ and $\Delta^\ast$ maps into $C\cap X$ (note that this is a dense open). The same argument shows that you can't extend the resulting map $\Delta^\times\to X^\mathrm{an}$ to a map $\Delta\to X^\mathrm{an}$.

PS, it's false that this is necessary as there are maps $\Delta^\ast\to \mathbb{P}^{1,\mathrm{an}}_\mathbb{C}$ that can't be extended (e.g. $z\mapsto \exp(-z^{-2})$). In fact, I don't know an example of an $X$ satisfying this, and a wise elder has suggested that perhaps there aren't any (e.g. $X$ essentially has to be a point). This would also corroborate why one cannot find this result in books.